# filter array and return specific property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following projection:

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    "satisfaction_rating.id": {"$exists": true}
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    "ticketId": "$id",
    "employee": "$assignee.name",
    "subject": "$subject",
    "memberId": {
      "$filter": {
         "input": "$custom_fields",
         "as": "field",
         "cond": {"$eq": ["$$field.id", 24685851]}
       }
    },
    "requester": "$requester.name",
    "created": "$created_at",
    "solved": "$metric_set.solved_at",
    "resolutionTimeInHours": {"$trunc": {"$divide": ["$metric_set.full_resolution_time_in_minutes.business", 60]}},
    "score": "$satisfaction_rating.score",
    "comment": "$satisfaction_rating.comment"
  }
},
{
  $out: "satisfaction"
}]);
```

$filter returns an array. What I want to do is to pick up the first element and get a property which should then be bound to memberId instead of an array with one element.

I was looking around for a while but didn´t find a suitable solution.
Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@user3100115 led me into the right direction.

Here my final solution:

```
"memberId": {
  "$let": {
      "vars": {
             "memberId": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                {"$filter": {
                        "input": "$custom_fields",
                        "as": "field",
                        "cond": {"$eq": ["$$field.id", 24685851]}
                }}
                ,0]
                }   
        },
        "in": "$$memberId.value"
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me. My issue was I was trying to use `$this` and it probably would have worked with just `this` and in any case it worked with `$$field`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator to return the element from [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)'s result and use the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator with the [*dot notation*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to access the sub-document field.

```
"memberId": {
    "$let": {
        "vars": { 
            "field": { 
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$custom_fields",
                        "as": "field",
                        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$field.id", 24685851 ]}
                    },
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "in": "$$field.id"
    }
}
```

Comment: One step further. But how can I get a property of that first element instead of the element itself.

Comment: Do you want only the `id` field?